# Как сделать чтобы программа не запускала процесс на каждый аргумент, а запускала один процесc на все аргументы?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Я написал MP3 Player на QT C++ и забилдил его. Когда я выделяю аудио и перетаскиваю на .exe программы она обрабатывает каждое аудио(тоесть воспроизводит и тд), но когда я выделяю эти файлы и способом "открыть с помощью" и выбираю свою програму, у меня на каждое аудио открывается по процессу и обрабатывает только его. Мне же нужно, чтобы открывался только один процесс и обрабатывал эти аудио.

Этим кодом обробляю аргументы:

```
if (argc > 1)
{

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        QString url = QString::fromLocal8Bit(argv[i]);
        w.addMediainPlaylist(url);
    }
    MainWindow::AudioPlayStatus status = MainWindow::THISorMAIN;
    w.PlayAudio(w.getPlaylist(),status);

}
```

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы запускать каждый аргумент в цикле, запустите один процесс и передайте все аргументы туда.

Comment: про что именно вы? как это реализовать?

Comment: В вашем исходном коде, который вы предоставили, у вас есть цикл, который перебирает аргументы командной строки, переданные при запуске программы. Затем для каждого аргумента вы вызываете функции `addMediainPlaylist` и `PlayAudio` вашего MP3 Player'а, что приводит к запуску нового процесса вашей программы на каждый файл MP3. Если что-то из этого не так, потрудитесь уточнить вопрос.

Comment: @DiMithras  при открытии мышкой винда открывает по процессу на файл по умолчанию. Там надо правильно прописаться в реестре чтоб все параметры передались вместе

Comment: @DiMithras , у меня в цикле происходит добавление всех аргументов - путей к файлам в список функцией addMediainPlaylist, а PlayAudio запускает одну из песен после их добавление тоесть после цикла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В QT для этого предусмотрен специальный класс [QtSingleApplication](https://docs.huihoo.com/qt/solutions/4/qtsingleapplication/qtsingleapplication.html) Для того чтобы быстро разобраться как он работает, предлагаю склонировать репозиторий примера выполнив команду:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt-solutions/qt-solutions.git
```

Далее выполнить билд, у меня Linux, поэтому для Windows может слегка отличаться в папке `qtsingleapplication` запустил последовательно 3 команды:

1. конфигурирование: `./configure`
2. создание мейкфайла: `qmake`
3. билд: `make`

После чего перешел в папку `qt-solutions/qtsingleapplication/examples/trivial/`

Там содержится программа с `GUI` при первом запуске она отображает пустое окно
с `TextEdit` а при повторных в `TextEdit` добавляются строки `"Wake up!"`

Делается это в main таким образом:

```
QtSingleApplication instance(argc, argv);  // получаем инстанс программы
if (instance.sendMessage("Wake up!"))      // тут можно прокинуть аргумент (?.mp3)
return 0;                                  // выходим не создавая второй инстанс
```

При первом запуске `sendMessage` не отрабатывает и мы не заходим в условие, но если экземпляр не закрыт то повторные запуски будут вести прямо в условие отсылая сообщение.

*В общем случае процесс выглядит приблизительно так: в системе регистрируется уникальный объект который можно каким-то образом найти. При запуске экземляра проверяется есть ли такой объект если он есть то программа завершается, между запуском и выходом есть возможность обработать аргументы, таким образом запуск программы служит не открытию нового окна а передаче аргументов уже открытому инстансу. По такому принципу действуют многие программы в системе, ярким примером может выступать браузер.*

Так же, возможно, пригодится эта ссылка https://evileg.com/ru/post/147/ в ней более подробно рассказывается о том что я написал выше.

Comment: Действительно, Ваш ответ мне помог. Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Создай ярлык программы. В ярлыке укажи шаблон параметров вроде `%I` ( или типа того , уточню завтра) и тогда при перетаскивании на ярлык будет открываться один инстанс с несколькими параметрами. Тоже самое и с "открыть с помощью", но там шаблон под параметр нужно исправить в реестре.

Comment: хорошо, буду ждать. Уточню, что при перетаскивании на .exe нескольких файлов всё работает как нужно, открывается один процесс со всеми аргументами. На счёт "открыть с помощью", Вы говорите про реестр, я себе на системе поменяю, но как быть с обычным юзером? Как можно будет это реализовать у него?

Comment: При первом запуске пропишите програмно

Comment: полистал тут доки, все немного изменилось со времен когда я это делал.  можно попробовать с https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-employ-the-verb-selection-model

, но лучше используй sendMessage - это более универсальный вариант для Qt.